# Using SSIS to run an Excel macro

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs a bunch of SSRS reports and saves them in a folder as `.xlsx` files.  I also have an Excel file with a macro that goes through each `.xlsx` file saved, consolidates into one file, formats and saves in another folder.

Right now this is a 2 step process, so my goal is to make it just 1 step.  To do that I'm trying to add a Script Task to the end of my SSIS package to open my Excel file with the macro and run it.

I have scoured the web looking for solutions for this and found many that seem to work for people, but aren't working for me.  Specifically, I'm using the code from [this site](http://bidn.com/Blogs/Execute-an-Excel-Macro-from-SSIS).

Now when I populate the code, add my reference to `Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library` and add the `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop` to the top of my script, I'm getting errors on some of the code.  Please see screenshot below:

[image]

The error I'm getting is:

**Reference to class 'ApplicationClass' is not allowed when its assembly is linked using No-PIA mode.**

I found [this site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5a06bf9-b38d-473c-8d90-6cbf6f37cd25/error-reference-to-class-applicationclass-is-not-allowed-when-its-assembly-is-linked-using?forum=vbgeneral) where someone seemed to have a similar issue, but it didn't help me with mine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the script somewhere?  See below for the script itself.

```
' Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
' Write scripts using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008.
' The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

 _
 _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum


    ' The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
    ' To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
    ' and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.
    '
    ' To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables("MyCaseSensitiveVariableName").Value
    ' To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, Nothing)
    ' To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, True)
    '
    ' To use the connections collection use something like the following:
    ' ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB")
    ' cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"
    '
    ' Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
    ' 
    ' To open Help, press F1.


    Public Sub Main()



        Dim oExcel As Excel.ApplicationClass = Nothing
        Dim oBook As Excel.WorkbookClass = Nothing
        Dim oBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing

        Try


            'Start Excel and open the workbook.
            oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oExcel.Visible = False
            oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks
            oBook = oBooks.Open(Dts.Variables("StrFilePath").Value.ToString()) ' Change your variable name here.


            'Run the macros.
            oExcel.Run("Format") ' Change the name of your Macro here.


            'Clean-up: Close the workbook and quit Excel.
            oBook.Save()
            oExcel.Quit()



            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

        Finally
            If oBook IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook)
            If oBooks IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks)
            If oExcel IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel)


            oBook = Nothing
            oBooks = Nothing
            oExcel = Nothing

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error message pretty much says it all... Use Application, not ApplicationClass. That, or turn off the Embed Interop Types in the properties for the Reference to the Excel library.

Comment: Thanks!  That got rid of the error!  However, now I'm getting this: Cannot load script for execution. 
I found a question on SO where someone else had that issue and they fixed it by just recreating the script task, but I tried that and it didn't work.  Any thoughts on that one?  I can open a new question if necessary

Comment: No idea, my area of expertise is the Office side of things... Better to open a new question :-)