# Runtime error when using a VBA script in SSIS

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ssis, runtime-error

I'm trying to run a VBA script in SSIS where it opens an excel file and saves it as a 1997-2003 excel file but I'm getting a runtime error whenever I execute. I've been using a combination of these two answers for my script: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25128962) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36334304) and I've come up with this:

## Script

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim oBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    '
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.Visible = False
    oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks
    oBook = oBooks.Open(Dts.Variables("Filename.xls").Value.ToString())
    oBook.SaveAs("Filename.xls")
    oExcel.Quit

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

I have references to both Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library and C#, can anyone help?

This is the error I'm getting:

DTS Script Task: Runtime error

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @EricBurdo Edited my post with it

Comment: Can you post the SaveAs method? Or do you want to save the file with `oExcel.Run("SaveAs")`

Comment: @Shmukko I'm only using a macro because I didn't think there was a way to save as a specific file type in a script task.

`Sub SaveAs()
'
SaveAs Macro
'

'
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "Filename.xls", FileFormat:=56
        

End Sub`

Comment: obook.saveas "" ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav ok that makes sense but would it be possible to save it as 1997-2003 specifically? Also, I'm still getting the runtime error

Comment: look at the signature and code of your macro, should be the same as oexcel is an instance of excel.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks a lot, I've fixed that now but I'm still getting the runtime error, do you know why?

Comment: Is Excel installed on the machine you're running this? Is the variable `filename.xls` pointing at the right file? Do you have R/W access to that file? Have you tried running the package in 32-bits mode(`Project``... properties`, `Debugging`, `Run in 64-bits mode --> false`) ?

Comment: @steenbergh Yes, excel is installed, filename is right and I have access. I've tried running in 32-bit but I still get the same runtime error. Is there anyway to see what exactly the error is?

Comment: You can set a breakpoint at the top of the VB code and step through it to see which line exactly throws the error - that might give some insight into what the error might be. Also, you might try specifiying a full path for that call to `wb.SaveAS()`; I'm not sure if it wants to save in the directory where the Excel file is now, or in the runtime-root of the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using. It opens the file in Excel and saves as Unicode text format. Also, make sure to turn 'Embed Interop Type' to False.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim xl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass()
    Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim laPath As String = "C:\Filename.xls"
    xlBook = DirectCast(xl.Workbooks.Open(laPath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
    oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
    oMissing, oMissing, oMissing), Workbook)

    xlSheet = DirectCast(xlBook.Worksheets.Item(1), Worksheet)
    xlBook.SaveAs("C:\Filename.txt", XlFileFormat.xlUnicodeText, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing)
    xl.Application.Workbooks.Close()
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```